# Interface between R and C

Tags: c, r

I have to call a C function from R. The function in C is called by:

```
void foo(int *s, char *bufin, unsigned char *bufout)
```

In R, I'm using:

```
.C('foo',s=as.integer(1:10),bufin=as.character('123456'),bufout=as.character('123456')).
```

R stops and freezes. The integer vector should be right, I suppose the error is in the way I pass bufin or bufout. Nobody knows a possible solution ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the body of `foo` please?

Comment: The body is necessary, to know for sure.  Additionally, passing the integer vector as an int may be wrong.  Might be better to pass it as a SEXP.

Comment: According to `?.C`, `character` vector should be passed as `char **` and not `char *`.